# Word 2007 prompts twice for "Opening this document will run the following SQL command" for Mail Merge

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, csv, mail-merge

I am trying to figure out why my mail merge in the a Word document is prompting me twice for seemingly two different data sources.  Both prompts look like the following:

[image].

The first prompt points the path where my `.csv` file resides, but then the prompt about appears directly afterwards if I click yes to the first.  The picture posted is the 2nd prompt that I receive.  **What's with the funky name on my `SELECT` statement and how do I eliminate the second prompt?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word 2007 copies some types of data source to a local folder. It's part 
of some security change. Unfortunately it is very difficult to tell in 
what circumstance Word will do this, but I think it is in essence when 
Word thinks it is opening a `field type` data source and it thinks it is 
on the Internet.

You should apply the registry change as described in the following [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825765).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome!  I'll give it a try once I can get to a place to test it!

Comment: My apologies, I just thought it gave it to you automatically.